# Numerical analysis: secant method. What am I doing wrong

Tags: matlab, numerical-methods

I'm trying to solve a problem regarding the application of the secant numerical method.

My MATLAB code is the following

```
function [f]= fsecante(t) 
R=24.7;
L=2.74;
C=0.000251;
P1=-0.5*(R/L)*t;
P2=t*sqrt(1/(L*C)-(R^2)/(4*L^2));
f=2*exp(P1).*cos(P2)-1;
end

%iteradas iniciais%
x0=0;
x1=10^-4;
wanted=10^-8;
f0=fsecante(x0);
f1=fsecante(x1);
iter=0;
error=wanted;

while(erro>=wanted)
    F=(x1-x0)/(f1-f0);
    xn=x1-F*f1
    error=abs(F*f1);
    iter=iter+1;
    x0=x1;
    x1=xn;
    f0=fsecante(x0);
    f1=fsecante(x1);
end
```

I used a calculator to get an idea about the value I should obtain which is 0.152652376 (approximately)
However using the method in MATLAB, it converges to 1.4204 which is way over what we should get. 
What am I doing wrong?
My guess is that I have my error variable wrong in the cycle? I also find strange that my solution goes of the set [0,1] where the solution should be. Can someone give me some clarification about what am I missing?

Comment: This question has already a good answer in the cross-post https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3036101/115115, essentially, there is nothing wrong, the initial points are just slightly unsuitable, setting `x1=1e-3` corrects that.

Answer (score 0):

If this is just about solving the equation, use

```
fsolve(@fsecante, 0)
```

to find the root of the function closest to `0`.

```
ans =   0.0257389353753764
```

---

You did nothing wrong, the secant method just does not converge for all initial points. Fast convergence is only guaranteed if convergence happens at all.

For a method using secant roots with a guarantee of convergence use the regula falsi method. In its Illinois variation it can be implemented as

```
x0=0
f0=fsecante(x0)
x1=1
f1=fsecante(x1)
wanted=10^-8;
iter=1;

while( abs(x1-x0) >= wanted)
    iter=iter+1
    F=(x1-x0)/(f1-f0);
    xn=x1-F*f1
    fn = fsecante(xn)
    if fn*f0 < 0 
      x1=x0; f1=f0;
    else
      f1 = f1*0.5;
    end
    x0=xn; f0=fn;
end
```

and gives the result for `x0=0; x1=1;`

```
init:  x0=     0                ,   f(x0)=   1
init:  x1=     1                ,   f(x1)=  -0.97824464599
n= 2:  xn=     0.5054986510525  ,   f(xn)=  -0.803719660003
n= 3:  xn=     0.28025344639849 ,   f(xn)=  -1.21180917676
n= 4:  xn=     0.081858845659703,   f(xn)=  -2.38168069197
n= 5:  xn=     0.007776289683393,   f(xn)=   0.848005195428
n= 6:  xn=     0.027227838393959,   f(xn)=  -0.090747663322
n= 7:  xn=     0.025347489826149,   f(xn)=   0.0235362327768
n= 8:  xn=     0.025734738800888,   f(xn)=   0.000253074462073
n= 9:  xn=     0.025743020435749,   f(xn)=  -0.000246366400381
n=10:  xn=     0.02573893523423 ,   f(xn)=   7.80359576957e-09
n=11:  xn=     0.025738935363624,   f(xn)=   2.40252262529e-13
n=12:  xn=     0.025738935363632,   f(xn)=  -2.39919195621e-13
```